# Square not highlighted in answers tab for accepted answer on meta

Tags: bug

If you provided an answer which was accepted on a meta site, the square is highlighted in the [summary tab](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2683/jasper-loy) but not in the [answers tab](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2683/jasper-loy?tab=answers). Is this inconsistency a bug?

Comment: It's being overridden by the `user-show-new` class; I'm not sure what that's for

Comment: no repro on Grainy beta metas